# Logback not outputting to file from logger

Tags: java, logging

I have the following logback XML configuration, however when I load my logger:

`private static final Logger LOGGER =  (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.nordea.icelink.adaptiv");`

And do and info log by dooing

`LOGGER.info(s);`

Nothing gets outputed to the file only on the console? How can this be?

```
<configuration>
<logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="WARN"/>

<logger name="com.nordea.icelink.adaptiv" level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>../logs/NordeaIceLinkServer.log</file>
<encoder>
  <pattern>%date{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm} %logger{36} %level %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>  
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>../logs/NordeaIceLinkServer.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
      <minIndex>1</minIndex>
      <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
 </rollingPolicy>
  <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
  </triggeringPolicy>   
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<encoder>
  <pattern>%logger{36} %level %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

```
<root level="debug">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
 </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a relative path for the log file.

```
<file>../logs/NordeaIceLinkServer.log</file>
```

Use an absolute one instead.

```
<file>/path/logs/NordeaIceLinkServer.log</file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the appender must be created before the logger. then it worked.